# how do you map values using regex in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a data frame called df:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Agent = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("dm_domain@domain01", 
"ns_name@namesrv200", "prodb101@webserver101"), class = "factor"), 
    Server = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("domain01", 
    "namesrv200", "proddb101"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Agent", 
"Server"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

There is a vector called app that contains the values:

```
 dput(app)
c("db", "dm", "ns")
```

I need to add another column to df called app and insert values of app that matches Agent column to app values. Here is df1 with end result:

```
dput(df1)
structure(list(Agent = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("dm_domain@domain01", 
"ns_name@namesrv200", "prodb101@webserver101"), class = "factor"), 
    Server = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("domain01", 
    "namesrv200", "proddb101"), class = "factor"), App = structure(1:3, .Label = c("db", 
    "dm", "ns"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Agent", "Server", 
"App"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

How could I do this in R, create a column in df and insert values to the column that matches Agent with app values?

Comment: You haven't really specified how the matching is supposed to occur.

Comment: @joran, if app is in the df$Agent, add that app value to the matching row in df as a new entry

Comment: I think your sample data is wrong too, `prodb101@webserver101` probably is reversed.

Comment: @Mike Wise, I need to search df$Agent with values in app and if there is a match, I need to insert app value in that row with column. I need final data frame to be df1.

Comment: You're leaving a lot of assumptions unsaid here. Are you assuming that the portion in `Agent` to match against is always before the `@` symbol? Are you 100% certain that, by chance, you won't have `dm` and `ns` occurring in the same `Agent`?

Comment: @joran, yes, match can happen anywhere in the Agent name

Comment: I would suggest a re-title to "how do you map values using regex in R". Would also print out the `df` formatted so people can see the data without parsing the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
app <- c("db", "dm", "ns")
names(app) <- c("proddb101", "domain01", "namesrv200")
df$App <- app[as.character(df$Server)]
df
#                   Agent     Server App
# 1 prodb101@webserver101  proddb101  db
# 2    dm_domain@domain01   domain01  dm
# 3    ns_name@namesrv200 namesrv200  ns
```

where `proddb101` is mapped to `db` and so on. `as.character` is necessary, as `df$Server` is of type `factor`.

Or, if you want to match more generally, you could do

```
app <- c("db", "dm", "ns")
vgrepl <- Vectorize(grepl, "pattern")
m <- vgrepl(app, df$Agent, fixed = TRUE)
df$App <- colnames(m)[max.col(m, "first")] # assign first match
df
#                   Agent     Server App
# 1 prodb101@webserver101  proddb101  db
# 2    dm_domain@domain01   domain01  dm
# 3    ns_name@namesrv200 namesrv200  ns
```

Comment: this wont work. I wont know which Server maps to App. I need to be able to search app in df$Agent and if match, then add it.

Comment: Have a look at my edit. The title, example and description of your question is a bit ambiguous imho.